# how to delimit double quotes in xslt

Tags: xslt, quotes

The following produces an xslt compilation error:

```
<asp:hiddenfield runat="server" value="<xsl:value-of select="string[position()=2]"/>"  id="<xsl:value-of select="$ActionID"/>"></hiddenfield>
```

How can I correctly get this statement to work?  I have tried the following, all with no success:
.
.
.
    '
    "
    
.
.
.
    " id="" />

and

```
<asp:hiddenfield runat="server" value="<xsl:value-of    select=&quot;string[position()=2]&quot;/>" id="<xsl:value-of select=&quot;$ActionID&quot;/>"></hiddenfield>
```

and

```
<asp:hiddenfield runat="server" value="<xsl:value-of select='string[position()=2]'/>" id="<xsl:value-of select='$ActionID'/>"></hiddenfield>
```

and

```
<asp:hiddenfield runat="server" value=&quot;<xsl:value-of select="string[position()=2]"/>&quot; id=&quot;<xsl:value-of select="$ActionID"/>&quot;></hiddenfield>
```

and

a bevy of other unsuccessful attempts either using concat, &#34, &#39, and more.  Where am I going wrong?  Many thanks to all responses in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be using Attribute Value Templates here!

Try this code instead

```
<asp:hiddenfield runat="server" value="{string[position()=2]}"  id="{$ActionID}"></asp:hiddenfield>
```

When you use curly braces in an attribute, this indicates it is an expression to be evaluated, rather than output literally.

Here is an alternate way of doing it.

```
<asp:hiddenfield runat="server">
   <xsl:attribute name="value">
       <xsl:value-of select="string[position()=2]"/>
   </xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:attribute name="id">
       <xsl:value-of select="$ActionID"/>
   </xsl:attribute>
```

However, as you can see, this is more verbose. You would only really need to use **xsl:attribute** if you wanted dynamic attribute names, or if you wanted to output an attribute only in certain conditions.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying for me.  We're having some network issues, so I cannot test your suggestion, but it seems sound to me.  A million blessings to you.  Thank you.

Comment: We finally got everything back up and running and I've tried both solutions you've listed, but I'm still receiving an XSLT compile error.  When I comment out only that section, everything runs fine.  There must a little more to it in this case...

Comment: Are you definitely sure you changed all occurrences of the attributes? Also, perhaps you could amend your question to show the exact error message you are getting? Thanks!

Comment: Hello, I actually commented out all occurrences, except for one, so that I can test it.  Both suggestions did not work, but I noticed the </asp:hiddenfield> tag was missing on the alternate suggestion.  When I entered the closing tag, voila!  Everything worked perfectly!  Thank God for people like you! You are awesome!  I'm not sure why the first suggestion does not work though, I went through it and made sure everything was entered correctly with no typos.